# Get Attachment which is of Type File from Rest API

Tags: community, rest-api

I'm trying to get attachments of type file from custom object through salesforce Rest API(outside of salesforce) but i'm not able fetch the file.

[image: This is the file i'm trying to get]

Getting below error

```
[{
    "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
}]
```

URL's i tried:

http://myinstance/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Document/069290000002n2kxxx/body/
http://myinstance/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Attachment/069290000002n2kxxx/body/
http://myinstance/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/SalesforceFiles/069290000002n2kxxx/body/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id which you have shared is [CONTENTDOCUMENT](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Standard-Field-Record-ID-Prefix-Decoder&language=en_US&type=1)

So your request will be

```
/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/ContentDocument/069290000002n2kxxx
```

[ContentDocument API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/ContentDocument/get-contentdocument-id)